# Windows 8 / IE 10 DNT feature

Tags: windows-8

> Do Not Track (DNT) The DNT header is available in Windows 8 to enhance
>   privacy online. This feature enables users to express their preference
>   about whether their browsing history should be collected and used for
>   targeted ads, content, and other purposes.

How to configure this feature for different Web application? like I want to share location with xyz.com but not with abc.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you turn off "Ask for location" in settings, then it will be off for all existing and future sites.

If you want some sites to know your physical location you will need to leave it on, and then allow/deny sites on a per-site basis - you can clear all data and start again.

Note that Location settings are different to the "Do Not Track" header, which is related to the cookies that are accepted or rejected by the browser.

[MS announced](http://securitywatch.pcmag.com/web-browsers/298596-microsoft-turns-on-do-not-track-by-default-in-ie10) that they were enabling DNT by default in IE 10, which apparently prompted many sites to announce that they were going to ignore the header when received from IE10 as they couldn't accurately determine if the user had explicitly set it.

In the desktop version of IE 10, you can configure the "Tracking Protection" settings from the Settings | Safety | Tracking Protection... menu.

More details about this are available from:

> [Tracking Protection Lists](http://www.iegallery.com/en-gb/tpl/FAQ)

Comment: "prompted many sites to announce that they were going to ignore the header" - Unless there's any binding legislation, that header value is going to be useless unfortunately.

Comment: @Karan indeed, certainly for IE10 users at any rate.

Comment: Why only IE10? DNT was first added to IE9 I believe, followed by FF4, Opera 12, Safari 6 and for obvious reasons last in Chrome 23 (after Google was [forced](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/print/9224543) to do so by the US Govt.) IE10 however is the first to enable it by default and naturally advertisers are up in arms over this simply to find *some* way of wriggling out. It's impossible for sites anyway to determine whether a human deliberately chose to enable the setting, plus Win8 does display a screen giving users the option of ignoring Express Setup (which turns DNT on).

Comment: I guess it's purely because it's "on by default", and it's not all that obvious how to change the settings. Personally, I'm fairly happy it's on by default, but I can see why advertisers are unhappy that a setting that was buried deep in a browser that most users would ignore and would break their models is now going to be turned on for the majority of users of that browser, and no one in their right mind will go in and turn it off (assuming they can find the setting) ;)

Comment: Precisely. They felt safe that hardly anyone (among non power users) would bother to go in and turn it on. Now they're angry because no-one will bother to specifically turn it off. When the previous situation (still the case with all other browsers) was so skewed towards them, did anyone see advertisers complaining? Like I said, there needs to be binding legislation that it should be enabled by default in all browsers, and sites cannot legally ignore it. Most online ads are bad enough without getting creepier and more targeted by the minute thanks to behavioural tracking. >:( Ad-blockers FTW!

Comment: @Karan don't forget Ghostery. There are plenty of trackers that aren't tied to advertisements. Hell, some of the companies that track your behavior across the web also happen to develop browsers or have all your social networking information (I'm sure you can figure out which companies I mean ;).

Comment: @kotekzot: Nope, haven't forgotten about it, although for users who want something that works right out of the box I recommend DNT+ instead since it blocks by default, unlike Ghostery that makes you decide (although it too can be set to block by default).